# Trouble reading java code

Tags: java

I have an engineering background and have had C programming in university. So I am used to thinking "do this, do that" kind of programming.

I started learning java because I want to know how to create an android app. I have a book here about Java and I watched quite a few youtube tutorials.

Even a simple beginners code like this causes me to wonder how to think and read a java code. I find this a huge obstacle at the moment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
```

Comment: You'll have to learn object oriented programming concepts. See [Oracle's Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: C is conceptually totally different from Java. [C vs Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/c2java.html). Start learning Java and OO programming and then you'll understand Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to study java, not attempt to learn it by just reading code.  Without some form of explanation/instruction on object-oriented programming, it will be difficult or impossible to just "figure this out" based on a non-OO language such as C.

onCreate is a method, otherwise known as a function or subprogram or subroutine; it is part of a class definition, there is a "public class X" or something similar above the declaration you have here.

Bundle is a class; an instance of it is passed as a parameter to this method.

`super` refers to the class which this class extends.  I don't have space here to explain inheritance, but along with "public class X" is "extends Y", and the code for `super.onCreate()` is in the class Y.

The call to setContentView is being passed a parameter from class R; the fact that the R is capital suggests it is a static variable `layout`, which then has another (possibly static) variable `activity_quiz`.

I think you need to start with a book explaining OO and basic Java before you try to understand code, even code like this.

Answer (score 0):

This method is called when activity started.
(see - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

- super() is used to call the parent constructor
- setContentView() set the user interface layout for this Activity